# pgr_withinPointsCost not calculating cost

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, network-analysis

I had the following SQL query working, but I can't seem to get it working again.  In summary, I have a set of points along a stream network that I would like to know the distance of along the stream.

When I run the query it returns a zero entry 'ccp_cost' table, but there are points downstream from the points.

My original points attribute table I imported into postgresql database:

| id | geom | ccp_no | pipeline | vel_lo | vel_hi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0101000020E6100000C428194AB75B5DC020AFB2B629984D40 | CCP 1.1 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0101000020E6100000DC837C757A5C5DC01005A568E59A4D40 | CCP 1.2 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0101000020E61000003CFA1521AB5A5DC0F808B831879D4D40 | CCP 3.2 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0101000020E610000090A17433ED575DC010781C5080A24D40 | CCP 4.2 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |
| 5 | 0101000020E6100000B8F5509179565DC05043215DC7A54D40 | CCP 4.3 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |
| 6 | 0101000020E6100000104AA99553525DC0403A538D03AE4D40 | CCP 6.2 | test pipeline | 0.2 | 1 |

Steps to query:

1.

```
-- ### Step 3 - Create attribute table structure and values required for running network analysis query.
ALTER TABLE migration.ccp ADD COLUMN pipeline varchar; -- add pipeline field
UPDATE migration.ccp SET pipeline='test pipeline'; -- add pipeline name
ALTER TABLE migration.ccp ADD COLUMN vel_lo float8; -- add low velocity field
UPDATE migration.ccp SET vel_lo = '0.2'; -- add velocity value
ALTER TABLE migration.ccp ADD COLUMN vel_hi float8; -- add low velocity field
UPDATE migration.ccp SET vel_hi = '1.0'; -- add velocity value
```

2. 

```
    -- ### Step 4 - Move release and CCP locations to stream and calculate fraction of stream CCP is located on
    -- We first need to get a candidate set of maybe-closest stream, ordered by id and distance.
    CREATE TABLE control_pts_events AS
    WITH ordered_nearest AS (
    SELECT
      ST_GeometryN(streams.geom,1) AS streams_geom,
      streams.id AS streams_id,
      pts.geom AS pts_geom,
      pts.id AS pts_id,
      pts.ccp_no,
      pts.pipeline,
      pts.vel_lo,
      pts.vel_hi,
      ST_Distance(streams.geom::geography, pts.geom::geography) AS distance_to_stream
    FROM migration.streams streams
      JOIN migration.ccp pts                        -- *** change to shapefile name ***
      ON ST_DWithin(streams.geom::geography, pts.geom::geography, 500) -- *** search distance away from stream ***
    ORDER BY pts_id, distance_to_stream ASC
    )
    SELECT
      DISTINCT ON (pts_id)
      pts_id,
      streams_id,
      ST_LineLocatePoint(streams_geom, pts_geom) AS fraction,
      distance_to_stream
    FROM ordered_nearest;
```

3. 

```
    -- Table for pgr_withPointsCost operation with the fraction of the stream a point is on & stream edge_id.
    CREATE TABLE cntrlpts_move AS
    SELECT
      events.pts_id AS id, events.fraction,
      ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_GeometryN(streams.geom, 1), events.fraction) AS geom,
      events.streams_id AS edge_id
    FROM control_pts_events events
    JOIN migration.streams streams
    ON (streams.id = events.streams_id);
```

4. 

```
-- Update control points table to include -pid
ALTER TABLE cntrlpts_move ADD COLUMN "pid" bigint;      -- add pid column for pg routing
UPDATE cntrlpts_move SET pid = -1*id;
          
-- Cost path from ccp to ccp
CREATE TABLE ccp_cost AS
WITH pgr_ccp AS (
SELECT r.*, p.*
FROM   pgr_withPointsCost(
         'SELECT id, 
                 source, 
                 target, 
                 length AS cost, 
                 reverse_cost
                 FROM migration.streams',
         'SELECT pid*-1 AS pid, 
                 edge_id, 
                 fraction 
                 FROM cntrlpts_move WHERE pid < 0',
            (SELECT pid FROM cntrlpts_move WHERE id = 1),
            ARRAY(SELECT pid FROM cntrlpts_move WHERE id > 1),  
            directed => true) AS r INNER JOIN cntrlpts_move AS p ON
            r.end_pid = p.pid
    ), ccp_distances AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_ccp 
    )
    SELECT * FROM ccp_distances ORDER BY agg_cost;
```

Comment: I now got it to work.  The stream data was discontinuous at the main branch, so nothing could route.